# How to get my queue:work to work on digital ocean server

Tags: linux, laravel, queue, digital-ocean, supervisord

i have a laravel project where i implemented queue,
on my local server everything works fine, if i run php artsan queue:work, it processes my jobs, but on digital ocean server, it doesnt work, if i run the same command, my terminal does nothing, i have tried everything possible, its not still working, i have setup supervisor, but its not processing anything,
if i run queue:listen, queue:work nothing happens, is there something blocking my queue from starting?

this happened to me some time ago on my local machine, but cant remember how it worked again then

i have been on this for 3days now no success

on my local machine it works fine, but on digital ocean the queue command doesnt work

## things that i have done already

i install supervisor, supervisor works well with no error, but doesnt process queue jobs

my broadcast driver is set to database

i hv migrated the jobs table

Comment: Gotta ask - Is your website under maintenance mode on production?

Comment: No!!
the website runs fine, in .env i set it to production, everything else works fine, just the jobs

Comment: so you run `php artisan queue:work` in your server correct?

Comment: yes!!
if i run php artisan queue:work
nothing happens 
even

Comment: yes!!
if i run php artisan queue:work
nothing happens 
even 
php artisan queue:listen

Comment: what do you mean with nothing happens, no return message? Maybe it just works did you test if it actually works?

Comment: yes nothing happens, i have jobs on my database, its not processed, i have cleared all jobs, even deleted the jobs table, and run queue:table, generated a new jobs table and do migration, test my email that i implemented shouldqueue, it didnt deliver but saw the job on my jobs table

Comment: Seems like you've done everything right. Have you checked error logs for errors that are not being reported when you run the queue worker?

Comment: how do i check error log on linux server, i log supervisor queue worker error, and on the error file nothing is showing, just blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this myself, let me post how i got this working, in case someone encounters such in the feature

the php artisan queue:work; was returning nothing on the terminal while it was logging the error in my laravel.log file
the error was that a column in the jobs table has exceeded 127 because it has been tried 128 times, 
i cleared the jobs table, run queue, this time I added tries=3, and all jobs failed after 3 retrials, so checking the log file, showed me errors that caused jobs to fail, fixing those error made my app to work well

Answer (score 0):

Incase if someone else is experiencing this in Digital Ocean App platform

in the worker use specify the queue and it will start to work for example

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=data,default,admin,integration &
```